# How to debug such memory corruption?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, crash

```
int main () {
       allocating_resource();
       call_other_libs();
       ...
       release_resource();
       return 0;
}
```

After the program runs, the main returns.

And after it accessed `returne 0`, the stack pointer points to a bad address in main(), then the executable crashed.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> GI __libc_free(mem=0x3f21a843) at malloc.c:2020

I guess there are some illegal memory accesses, but the code base is too
large to check. Review and analyse all the code is not realistic.

Disable some code is also unacceptable due to large code base.

With core dump there 's no hint I can use due to it's crashed at the main  stack and after the return clause executed.

I know how to use gdb, but the project is so large that it seems to hard to find the root cause.

valgrind --tool=memcheck seems to no help.

How to solve such problem?

Comment: You are passing an invalid pointer to free, I suppose. Compile with debugging symbols and use a debugger (e.g. gdb on UNIX) and break on calls to free.

Comment: There is no possible magic; if the code is big, searching for a bug is a difficult task. Track first which freeing cause the crash and then try to track back from that...

Comment: see my updated answer. there is one more tool called valgrind that can detect memory related issues. This applies if your issue is memory related.

Comment: answer updated again.

Comment: what about MemProf. I have added in answer. I know this may help you because it gives function by function and also detects allocated and unreferenced memory.

Comment: "*valgrind --tool=memcheck seems to no help.*" Why?

Comment: In case you are facing stack issues Valgrind's (experimental) stack checker tool (`exp-sgcheck`) might help you : http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html

Comment: if valgrind is not able to pinppoint some memory allocation/free problem, then the most likely case is some allocated memory as be overrun, like an buffer input overrun or a array of pointers overrun.

Comment: Suggest a good first step would be replace the `call_other_libs();
       ...` with a stub that does nothing, then see if the problem still exists.  If the problem disappears, then the source of the problem is the call_other_libs() function.   Similar such testing could be used to progressively add/remove code until the problem disappears, then narrow the debugging efforts to that small area that was skipped.  To avoid a lot of editing, use the #if 0 ... #endif to cause a block of code to be skipped (after a re-compile/re-link/rerun

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix all those warnings,  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  Suggest  also using `-Wconversion` and `-std=c99`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use GDB.
This [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis) has details about how to debug using GDB. If you google, you can get many such helpful links on GDB.

 You can also use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), if you are sure about memory related issues.

There is one more memory profiler called [MemProf](http://www.secretlabs.de/projects/memprof/). It gives memory allocated for each function and can also detect issues. See the link for details.
There are also c++ specific tools for memory profiling like:
[mempro](http://www.puredevsoftware.com/mempro/index.htm) and [MTuner](http://mtuner.net/). You can use trial version for free.

Comment: the log doesn't help, because the program crashed after the main return.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are not having some kind of code access here, I'll have to assume that in some magic way free is called when the scope of main is destroyed (maybe the use of smart pointers? maybe some sophisticated macro definitions... can't really tell). I would try to recreate the problem in the following manner:

```
int main () 
{
       {
           allocating_resource();
           call_other_libs();
           ...
           release_resource();
       }
       return 0;
}
```

or

```
  int main()
  {
    mainhelper();
    return 0;
  }
```

where mainhelper will contain the main code.

Hopefully after those steps the problem will persist and the logs won't be completely damaged, as you suggest, because the program is terminating.

also, try to play with the optimization flags (more like in disabling it) and add `-ggdb3` debug flag (assuming gcc here). Maybe it will help you in some bizarre way.

Some other posts concerning this matter, if you haven´t checked them out yet:

[segmentation fault after main returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807889/segmentation-fault-after-main-returns)

[Program receives SIGSEGV error after return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131832/program-receives-sigsegv-error-after-return-0)

they are all stating more of the same: `valgrind` should be able to deliver an answer.